# Proof regarding finding the two sets $S$ and $T$ are equinumerous

Tags: real-analysis

I have a hard time doing this proof.  Can anyone help me?

> Show that the following pairs of sets S and T are equinumerous by finding a
>   specific bijection between the sets in each pair.
>
> $S = [0,1]$ and $T = [0,1)$

Comment: Can you find a bijection between $\{0,1,2\ldots\}$ and $\{1,2,\ldots\}$?

Comment: ... and then, can you extend the idea to find a bijection between $\{1, 1/2, 1/4, \dots\}$ and $\{1/2, 1/4, \dots\}$? Then the bijection between $S$ and $T$ can be the identity map on the **complements** of these two sets.

Comment: I think I got the proof done!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've probably seen that the identity map won't work because isn't a bijection. The $1$ in the set $S$ can't be mapped to $1$ in the set $T$, because $1 \notin T$.

So we have the identity map but with the caveat that we try to map the $1$ in $S$ to something else. Say we send it to $\frac{1}{2}$. This causes a new problem, obviously. Lets send the $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{3}$. This causes another new problem. Continuing in this manner, we end up with the identity map for most of the elements of $S$, but we're doing something different to a small (but countably infinite) subset of $S$.

Namely, we are mapping $\frac{1}{n}$ to $\frac{1}{n+1}$ for $n > 0$ (where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$).

I'll leave it to you to get this down into proper maths, but I think I've given you the gist of the argument that you need to make.